# Comparable Class and Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I need to create an abstract 'Comparable' class. Any class that inherits from this class will implement a compare_to method.

```
/* returns 1 if this class > rhs, 0 if equal, -1 if this class < rhs */    
int compare_to(const Comparable& rhs);
```

Create a Binary Search Tree class which stores "Comparable" objects rather than integers.

What I'm having trouble with is understanding what the Binary Search Tree class will look like and how we can store Comparable objects in it.

We can use Templates.

Comment: In C#, comparable objects inherit from an `IComparable` interface.  Maybe you can do something similar in C++.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.  Are you asking what a Binary Search Tree is?  Are you asking how to implement a class so it's "Comparamble"?  In your attempt to answer these questions, what have you tried?

Comment: What's the point you're having problem with: the BST implementation or using Comparable class to abstract away the details of actual members of the tree?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, don't make any general interface. This has many drawbacks. What if two classes derived from IComparable are not comparable to each other - like Int and String?

You said you can use templates. Use them - and provide Comparator as second template arguments:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
class BSTree  {
public:
   bool present(const T& value)
   {
       int res = comparator(value, root->value);
       switch(res) {
         case 0: return true;
         case -1: return find(root->left, value);
         case 1: return find(root->right, value);
       }
   }
private:
  struct Node {
  ...
  };
  Node* root;
  Comparator comparator;
};
```

Typical comparator would be:

```
template <class T>
class RawComparator {
public:
    int operator()(const T& l, const T& r) 
    {
       if (l < r) return -1;
       else if (l > r) return 1;
       else return 0;
    }

};
```

And your binary search tree for int:

```
typedef BSTree<int, RawComparator<int>> BSTreeInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to create class template for binary search tree.
class template will look something like

```
template <typename Comparable>
class BSTNode
{
public:
BSTNode const Comparable & theElement = Comparable( ),BSTNode *lt = NULL, BSTNode *rt = NULL);
int size( BSTNode *t ) ;
int height( BSTNode *t);
void printPostorder( ) ; 
void printInOrder( ) ; 
void printPreOrder( ) ;
bool operator<(const Comparable&,const Comparable &); 
BSTNode *duplicate() ;


public:

Comparable element;
BSTNode *left;
BSTNode *right;

};
```

And then you can overload `operator<` to add the comparison method for `Comparable` type objects.